# While loop doesn't work on php

Tags: php, mysql, while-loop

```
<?php

if (!($database = mysqli_connect("localhost", "root", "","gem"))) {                           
    die( "Connexion non possible à la base de données." );
}

$requete = "SELECT nom_eta FROM etablissements ";
$query = "SELECT * FROM formations";

if ( !( $result = mysqli_query($database, $requete) ) OR !( $resulta = mysqli_query($database, $query) )) {
    print( "Impossible d'exécuter la requête! <br />" );
    die( mysqli_error($database) );
}

while ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result) ) {
    $data=$row;
?>
    <a href="#"><?php echo $data['nom_eta'];?></a>
<?php
    while ($ligne = mysqli_fetch_assoc($resulta) ){
        $donnee=$ligne;
        if($data['nom_eta']==$donnee['nom_eta']) {
        ?>
            <ul>
                <a href="#"><?php echo $donnee['formation'];?></a>
            </ul>
        <?php
        }
    } 
}
?>
```

Myproblem is, there are other data should be shown under ENSAT & ENCGT but there is some kind of problem in re-executing the WHILE-LOOP..

Comment: I'd format the code to something more readable if I were you. Also what is ENSAT&ENCGT? there is nothing like that in the code???

Comment: That `if` and `OR` combo just looks horribly suspicious, that _and_ you seem to be using `mysqli_` as a 1-on-1 copy of `mysql_*`, which it just **isn't**

Comment: @Elias Van Ootegem I worried about the IF ... OR too, but I think it's ok.

Comment: @BigScar: Yeah, it should be fine, but I see no reason why the OP is using the low-priority `OR` here, perhaps OP is unaware of the difference between `OR` and `||`, and I was hoping my comment would encourage him to RT(f)M

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You shouldn't nest the whiles, instead run the second one before and assign the results to an array, then you can loop over the array inside the other while

```php
<?php
if ( !( $database = mysqli_connect( "localhost","root", "","gem")))                           
  die( "Connexion non possible à la base de données." );
$requete = "SELECT nom_eta FROM etablissements ";
$query = "SELECT * FROM formations";
if ( !( $result = mysqli_query($database, $requete) ) OR !( $resulta = mysqli_query($database, $query) )) {
  print( "Impossible d'exécuter la requête! <br />" );
  die( mysqli_error($database) );
}

$ligne = array();
while ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($resulta)) {
  $ligne[] = $row;
}

while ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result) ){
  $data=$row;
  ?><a href="#"><?php echo $data['nom_eta'];?></a><?php

  foreach ($ligne as $donee) {

    if($data['nom_eta']==$donnee['nom_eta']){
      ?><ul><a href="#"><?php echo $donnee['formation'];?></a><?php ?></ul><?php
    }
  } 
}
?>
```